# convergence of Poisson integral

Tags: fourier-analysis

If  $f\in L^p(S_1)$ then does it's Poisson integral on the disk $D$ converge to $f $ nontangentially  almost surely ( i.e. radially as r tends to 1) ?? How one should prove this if such result is true?? (Here $S^1$ means unit circle and $D$ is open unit disc).